# MS Access Loop through using results from DLookup

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list of paths stored in a table (tmpCampaignPaths \ field = CampaignPaths).  I want to loop through each one and create the folder.  I have the function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists to do this.  However, when I run the below it only ever creates the first path\record from the table - what am I missing? How come its not looping through?  Is it because I'm using the DLookup to retrieve the path?

```
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset


Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tmpCampaignPaths")

rs.MoveFirst

Do While Not rs.EOF

MakeSureDirectoryPathExists DLookup("CampaignPaths", "tmpCampaignPaths")

rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recordset loop already gives you the values - there is no need for `DLookup`.

```
Do While Not rs.EOF

    MakeSureDirectoryPathExists rs!CampaignPaths

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

`DLookup` without criteria will always give the value from the first record.